# Reversing a Linked List with 2 pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list using only two pointers (every post i've viewed seems to use 3 but my requirement for the assignment is 2)

So i'll start with how I approached this. Currently the values are linked as such nullptr -> (head)1->2-> ... -> 7->8->nullptr, where the values being reversed are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

```
void reverseList(){
    ListNode *last = head;
    ListNode *current = last->next;

    if(current == nullptr) return;

    while(current != nullptr){
         current->next = last;
         last = current;
         current = last->next;
    }
}
```

Logically, on paper my loop works, but it is an infinite loop in my ide and debugger.

I also tried making a loop to check size and go from the end, where head = 8 and tail = 1 but that also didn't work.

I also tried a binary search approach where I found the mid point and did +- mid and swapped, but I have no way of going from 4->3 as well.

My goal of this is to go from 1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8 to 8->7->6->5->4->3->2->1

Comment: fill in the `while` loop with your logic to really see if it works.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry! Added and I realized something that might work but is an infinite loop, added it

Comment: "Logically, on paper my loop works" You need better logic or better paper. The only way to move past `current`  is to take the original `current->next`,  but you overwrite it before looking at it.

Comment: If you have a function that accepts `head` and is allowed two other pointer variables, then you have three in total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making it simpler, moving `head` ptr instead.

Since your `display()` starts first in `head`.

```
void reverseList(){
    ListNode* current = head->next;

    if(current == nullptr) return; // list is empty

    head->next = nullptr;

    while(current != nullptr) { // have we reached the end of a forward list?
        ListNode* next = current->next;
        current->next = head; // reverse next pointer to "previous" node
        head = current;       // move last pointer to "current" node
        current = next;       // move to "next" node
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that only prints out 2->nullptr; I debugged it and it enters the loop 3 times though.

Comment: Thanks for helping! But it still does the same thing. I just wanted to add, we don't need to return anything as it is all part of one big class / struct. I am trying to debug as we speak

Comment: Yes, I have the original printed out. The whole source code is as follows: https://pastebin.com/GEC0Un9d

Comment: I just checked the pointer value of current and it is progressing, is it my display function?

Comment: I added current->next = nullptr before the loop and head = current after the loop instead of head->next = nullptr. This should work with my display but doesn't. really frustrating :

Comment: Works! Thank you. I will study it to understand how to do it better. Made it answer

Answer (score 0):

When the loop gets entered for the first time, current points to '2'. Then this happens:

- current->next get's modified (!) to head.

So the list is now (head)1->2->(last==head)1->2->1->2->1 ... You've created a loop. That is why your program never terminates.